# Inspect Element Greyed out in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, inspect-element

Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 m.

All of a sudden one day Inspect Element option in right button context menu greyed out. Ctrl + Shift + I doesn't do anything and F12 doesn't do anything. Cleaned the cache as suggested by one answer here but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that for strange reasons, either Windows update or Chrome update changed this registry setting.

Software/Policies/Google/Chrome/DeveloperToolsDisabled to 1. Changed it to 0 and restarted the system.

Answer (score 0):

go to your software, then go into policies, google ,chrome ,then you see DeveloperToolsDisabled is at 1, change it to 0. DONE

Comment: Write more detailed answer. It is about registry modification? Write about it. And use [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for better style.