# Inspect chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I right-click on a website in chrome (I have Mac), the word inspect is greyed out. Can someone help me? [Screenshot with proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJSW7.png)

Comment: Possible dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529213/inspect-element-greyed-out-in-chrome

Comment: Nvm, I don't need it. I was trying to figure it out for Cookie Clicker, but I realized it was in the debug menu.